# What's mullet they are saying in this video?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGc-ZawSoyE&t=944s

I found the meaning of 'mullet' in dictionary and it's a fish..?
Does it mean a real fish what they are saying in this video about Ezra's hair ..?

Comment: A [*mullet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mullet_(haircut)) is a hair-style that became popular in the 1970s.

Comment: One question per post, please; you can ask the other question separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ezra is trying to describe his haircut.

As the guy in the baseball cap says:

> I know for a fact that growing the back out..., it's mullet style

[image]
<sub>(source: [machohairstyles.com](http://machohairstyles.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Pat-Sharp%E2%80%99s-Mullet.jpg))</sub>

but this is Ezra in the movie *Fantastic Beasts and Where To Find Them*

[image]

with the mushroom cap he mentioned.